# Templates: Using partial templates gives wrong number of arguments error

Tags: templates, c++11, compiler-errors

I declare two classes like this:

```
template<typename Data, const int m, const int n>
class Foo {};

template<typename Data, const int m>
class Foo <Data, m, 1> {};
```

Now when I try the following (pretty much the class for double, but it behaves like anything else so a new partial class would be an overkill):

```
template <const int n>
using BarD = Foo<double, n>; // error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 3)
```

Why is that happening? Is there some concept I didn' fully understand?

PS: I use eclipse 4.3.1 M20130911-1000 and build with g++ -O3 -g -Wall -c -std=c++11 -o obj/c++/src/test.o src/test.cpp

Comment: You confuse specialization with default template parameters. And there is no `Mat` template in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a default argument in the primary declaration:

```
template<typename Data, int m, int n = 1>
class Foo {};

template<typename Data, int m>
class Foo <Data, m, 1> {};
```

Also, you don't need `const int`, only `int` in the template declarations.

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand your answer a bit? Maybe explain shortly (2 sentences) the difference between specialization and default template parameters just for the sake of a complete explanatory answer.

Comment: Sure.  Foo is a templated class that takes three parameters:  a type, an int and another int, the last of which can be omitted by the code instantiating it.  Think of a template specialization as just an implementation of a templated class where the pattern matches.  A specialization cannot change how it is "called"; it just changes how it is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

For a given `template`, specializations do not extend the interface -- the kind and number of parameters that your `template` takes.

Specialization is not like overloads.  Instead it is pattern matching on the arguments that the original `template` specified.

The `template` parameters of a specialization are never passed by client code directly, but are instead pattern match deduced by how they are used.

So

```
template<typename Data, int m> class Foo <Data, m, 1> {};
```

and

```
template<int m, typename Data> class Foo <Data, m, 1> {};
```

are identical specializations, even though i changed the order of `m` and `Data`.  The order that (for the most part) matters is after the `Foo`, where how the **original** `template` arguements are ordered is used, and any `template` arguments from the specialization are placed for the purpose of pattern matching.

If the pattern is matched, then the specialization applies (well if multiple specializations match, more rules follow).